# Cleaning inline instances

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-orm

Consider these pseudo models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    code = models.CharField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    price = models.DecimalField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()

class AlternativeProduct(Product):
    original_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="alternative", editable=False)
```

I want to use inlines to be able to quickly add a product and its alternative option without typing duplicate data (ONLY code, stock and price differentiate).

**admin.py**

```
class AlternativeProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AlternativeProduct
    formset = AlternativeProductInlineFormset
    fk_name = "original_product"
    fields = ["code", "price", "in_stock"]
    max_num = 1
    extra = 0


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductAdminForm
    inlines = [AlternativeProductInline]
```

Ofcourse this will raise `ValidationError`, because `AlternativeProduct` is missing a `category`.

Now I could setup a default value to fix that:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    code = models.CharField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
```

But besides the fact this id might not exist it still needs to be corrected. Is there any other way (besides Javascript) to copy the category value of the genuine product to the alternative inline product '***under the hood***'

I have tried to change the admin_view, but it gets hackish, perhaps a custom view would be a nice solution although javascript is a less time consuming approach.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code snippets, particularly `models.py`. Are you sure nothing has been lost in translation to "pseudo" models? In particular, you refer to fields on `AlternativeProduct` that don't seem to exist.

Comment: Sorry, typo, AlternativeProduct derives from Product

Comment: What is the difference between `Product` and `AlternativeProduct`? Right now, it seems they shouldn't be two separate models.

Comment: Let's say the db is populated with 10 OEM products, every product can have an alternative branded product, which is EXACTLY the same except for stock and price. Since these two products are really bound together I don't want to fill an entire form for both (thus twice as much work). It seems less time consuming to do it this way.

Comment: I separated Price and Stock at first (with a choices field defining genuine/alternative), which worked, but felt highly impractical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript does seem to be the easy approach to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#alternative-group thead th:nth-child(2)').hide();
    $('#alternative-group tbody td:nth-child(1) p').hide();
    $('#alternative-group tbody td:nth-child(3)').hide();
    $('#id_alternative-0-category').hide();

    var product_category = $('#id_category option:selected').val();
    $('#id_alternative-0-category').val(product_category);

    $("#id_category").change(function() {
        product_category = $('#id_category option:selected').val();
        $('#id_alternative-0-category').val(product_category);
    });
});
```